# IdentityServer3 - Contacting IdP after user is authenticated

Tags: identityserver3, azure-ad-b2c

We have SPA, IdSvr3, and a third party IdP(AAD B2C).

The user authenticates successfully. When the user clicks an edit profile link in the SPA, they are directed to IdSvr using the authorization_endpoint. I pass in an acr_value called "profile."

I believe this is the same problem as this gentleman- https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2816#issuecomment-217161898

I've tried a few things:

1. Implemented ICustomRequestValidator.ValidateAuthorizeRequestAsync.- In this method, I retrieve the acr_values. There doesn't appear to be a good way to direct the user from here. There is the RedirectUrl on the ValidatedAuthorizeRequest that does redirect the user, but all the information on that object is from the client request to IdSvr and is not relevant to the IdP.

   - Perhaps there is a setting on the ValidatedRequest that could be tweaked to force IdSvr to direct over to the identity provider(in this case the IdP is - Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthentication)
2. Implemented a UserService. If the user is logged in, the events trigger IsActiveAsync and GetProfileDataAsync. In IsActiveAsync I can get the acr value from the HTTP context, and set IsActive to false, forcing IdSvr to go back to the IdP. I can't access the context from OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications.RedirectToIdentityProvider, so I haven't found a way to access the acr value there. Is there a way to pass something into here to check if this should be an edit profile?
3. Similar to the UserService I've implemented IsAuthenticationSessionValidAsync to invalidate the session and force the idsvr to direct to the Idp. This has the same issue of not being able to access the acr value.
4. PartialLogin doesn't appear to be the right strategy for this either because it appears to only be triggered from a user who isn't authenticated yet. Perhaps if we force the user to log-out, this could be used to direct them to the IdP? https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/userService.html

Logging the user out feels like the wrong approach to begin with, but it seems like it could be made to work.

Is there a standard way of intercepting a request and directing it over to the IdP based on something in the request?